# Python, mysqldb error 1064

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

So I have the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'I, Alexander_Bernard16@milton.edu, D0NBT6)' at line 1")
```

---

Here's my code:

```
cnx = MySQLdb.connect(
    user=username, passwd=password, host=hostname, db=databaseName)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists gotchaTable(id int(11) PRIMARY KEY "
               "AUTO_INCREMENT, selfFirstName TEXT NOT NULL, selfLastName TEXT NOT NULL, "
               "selfGrade TEXT NOT NULL, selfCode TEXT NOT NULL, targetCode TEXT NOT "
               "NULL);")
cnx.commit()

add_data = (
    "INSERT INTO gotchaTable (selfFirstName, selfLastName, selfGrade, selfCode, targetCode) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4});"
)

studentlist = []
with open('Gotcha.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    gotchaData = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in gotchaData:
        student = Student(
            row['First'], row['Last'], row['Class'], row['Email'])
        studentlist.append(student)
studentlist = randomList(studentlist)
for x in xrange(1, len(studentlist)):
    studentlist[x].target = studentlist[
        x + 1] if x < len(studentlist) - 1 else studentlist[0]
    cursor.execute(add_data.format(studentlist[x].first, studentlist[x].last, 
        studentlist[x].grade, studentlist[x].email, 
        studentlist[x].code, studentlist[x].target.code))
    cnx.commit()
    print studentlist[x].getData()
```

---

And here's my student class:

```
class Student(object):

"""docstring for Student"""

def __init__(self, f, l, c, e):
    self.first = f
    self.last = l
    self.grade = c
    self.email = e
    self.code = id_generator()
    self.target = None

def getData(self):
    return self.first + ' ' + self.last + ' ' + self.grade + ' ' + self.email + ' ' + self.code
```

---

Im trying to make a program that gets data from a csv (which already works) and puts it into a SQL table. How do i fix the error 1064, i've tried using "%s" instead of '{0}' but i get the same error. Any suggestions?

the id_generator() method returns a string of random characters.
randomList(a) makes the array random.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use string formatting to parameterize an SQL query** - this is dangerous and, as you can see, error-prompt. Instead, let the MySQL driver worry about it:

```
add_data = """
    INSERT INTO 
        gotchaTable 
        (selfFirstName, selfLastName, selfGrade, selfCode, targetCode) 
     VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
"""
```

Then, when you call `execute()` pass parameters in a separate argument:

```
cursor.execute(add_data, [
    studentlist[x].first, 
    studentlist[x].last, 
    studentlist[x].grade, 
    # studentlist[x].email,  ALSO WATCH THIS ONE (there are only 5 placeholders in the query)
    studentlist[x].code, 
    studentlist[x].target.code
])
```